# Rewrite rule in nginx webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I still struggling with make rewrite rule in my webserver. When I tryin login (www.example.com/admin/) to my backend I have only white page. But If I try to add index (www.example.com/admin/index) or index.php (www.example.com/admin/index.php) my backend is working. So how can I edit code for function www.example.com/admin/ ?

Thanks a lot for any help!

There is my code:

```
 server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.php;
        server_name www.example.com;


    location /admin/ {
        rewrite ^ /admin/index.php;
    } 

   location / {
        rewrite ^([^\.]*)$ /$1.php;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
      }
}
```

Comment: this is my error [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:18 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
location /admin/ {
    rewrite ^ /admin/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Hey BaBL86! Thanks for help but now when I trying to restart nginx show me error...

Comment: And you don't want to show me this error? I need to use my telepathy?

Comment: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:18
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: @BaBL86 Thanks for Answer but when I use your code my site is redirected to admin.example.com. So I need www.example.com/admin/... Do you have any idea ?